# Log4Net incorrect conversion pattern with generic class and precision argumen

Tags: c#, log4net

The C# logging framework log4net appears to incorrectly handle generic class names across all loggers and appenders when used in a conversion pattern with a precision argument (e.g. `%logger{1}`). Because I was unable to find any related issues / questions at all, I decided to post a detailed rundown of the issue in the hopes that someone would know a fix / workaround.

For example, the generic class `DiskSaviourHook<T>` with the aforementioned conversation pattern is supposed to produce `DiskSaviourHook`, but instead outputs `0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]` (which is obviously wrong). Upon further investigation I found that this is because the log4net parsers just look for the last dot when used with a `{1}` precision argument.

More specifically, the logger name `Sigma.Core.Training.Hooks.Saviors.DiskSaviorHook'1[[Sigma.Core.Architecture.INetwork, Sigma.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]` is treated like any other logger name, despite it being generic and having more dots than usual (the last dot of the version is handled like the last dot of the actual class). Is there any known fix / workaround to this issue?

Comment: Why would you give your logger an unwieldy name like that? It's a persistent misconception (not aided by the documentation) that you *must* use class names for loggers. This works out especially poorly in the case of generics, as you've discovered. I'd say the issue is not that the precision argument is somehow malfunctioning (it is not), it's that the class name isn't divested of its type parameter signature (complete with assembly). Complicating the hierarchy naming rules for this case doesn't seem right either.

Comment: `LogManager.GetLogger(Type)` is implemented as `LogManager.GetLogger(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly(), type.FullName)`. This is arguably a bad idea given generics. I'd make it `LogManager.GetLogger(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly(), type.Namespace + type.Name)`, which omits expanding the type arguments for generics. Obviously client code is free to do this as well, though it's clumsy.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thank you very much, I did indeed not realise that. I have now made all loggers use this "fixed" name, which works out fine. They really should mention that somewhere though... anyway, do you want to post that as an answer (points)?

Comment: May as well, along with an even simpler workaround. If you really *wanted* the generic name including parameters as the logger name *and* you wanted to get the class name in the layout, however, it would be a lot more difficult; you'd probably need a custom property or even a custom layout. I imagine most people would be satisfied with just not having the generic parameters, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversion pattern is working fine. In log4net,  logger names are hierarchical, and the hierarchy's levels are separated by periods. This *happens* to align quite neatly with how classes are named in namespaces, so it's a widespread practice to use class names for logger names (thereby making it easy to configure logging for an entire namespace). So widespread that log4net has overloads for it: `LogManager.GetLogger(Type)` is implemented as `LogManager.GetLogger(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly(), Type.FullName)`.

Unfortunately this doesn't play nice with generics. A generic type has a `FullName` that includes its type parameters, which breaks the hierarchy log4net uses. You can still have a logger named `Sigma.Core.Training.Hooks.Saviors.DiskSaviorHook'1[[Sigma.Core.Architecture.INetwork, Sigma.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]`, of course, but as far as log4net is concerned this has a particularly ugly hierarchy that includes components like `DiskSaviorHook'1[[Sigma`. The hierarchy is purely syntactical, not based on parsing the actual class name. Indeed, using class names for loggers is just a convention, albeit a useful one.

If I was a log4net developer and not concerned with backwards compatibility I'd implement `LogManager.GetLogger(Type)` as `LogManager.GetLogger(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly(), Type.Namespace + Type.Name)`, which doesn't suffer from this problem. But I'm not and I'm also too lazy to open an issue.

For client code, there's a simple workaround. Replace code like this:

```
static ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(DiskSaviourHook<T>));
```

with either this:

```
static ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(DiskSaviourHook<>));
```

or this:

```
static ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(
    System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType
);
```

The latter is mentioned in the documentation as a piece of boilerplate to get the class name without mentioning it, and it will also do "the right thing" for generics. (I still prefer to simply put in the class name myself over reflection.)

Comment: About the last version (`GetLogger(
    System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType`) - that one doesn't work with generics. It's the one I originally used before you mentioned the `GetLogger(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly(), Type.Namespace + Type.Name)` version, are you sure that should work? It suffers from the same problem as using `GetLogger(Type)` because it's the same function.

Comment: @1337: I based my assertion on the fact that `System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.FullName` gives back the class name sans expanded parameters. And testing with log4net 1.2.13, doing this form a generic class indeed logs `%logger{1}` as `GenericClass\`1`, without the parameters. If your experience is different, more details are needed.